# Wifi adapter not found, Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, 18.04, mediatek

I installed dual boot Ubuntu with Windows, but I have a problem with WiFi because it doesn't work. I tried to fix it but I wasn't successful. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what’s too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fix your first error:**

`linux-headers-amd64` should be `linux-headers-generic`

**Fix your second error with:**

`sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.l /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list`

**Fix your third error with:**

Edit `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` and remove the leading " from line 8 that contains "options" (same for the end of that line, if it exists).